Is there a way to skip 2FA while using fastlane spaceship app analytics?
I want to show AppStoreConnect's app analytics in my web app. Using fastlane/spaceship(fastlane gem) to get metrics from AppStoreConnect. Unbale to proceed due to 2FA. I just want to skip the 2FA which is prompted after login command. Is there a way to skip apple's 2FA?

There seems to be a plethora of questions and suggestions around this issue. Have you tried implementing any of them? Also this section of the docs Using App Store Connect API seems like it would be very relevant and this Comment states "...since the App Store Connect API and fastlane now support JWT auth. This API token replaces the need for user/pass credentials, and thus 2FA hacks and workarounds."

App Store Connect API doesn't support app analytics.

The API definitely supports Analytics, maybe fastlane doesn't support this?
